# Question(s) Regarding the Lindhard Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

As a theoretical chemist, I'm slightly outside of my element on a project my advisor gave me, so I come to your for help and direction.
Basically, he wants me to integrate the imaginary part of the Lindhard Function (over both q and omega). He says that doing so will give me the exchange energy of the uniform electron gas. He keeps telling me that Dirac wrote this down somewhere but I can't seem to find any evidence of that.

Furthermore, whenever I try to do this integral, I get infinity. I've used Vignale and Giuliani as a reference for the formula, as well as Mahan. Each book reports the integrand differently, the former opting for the use of step functions, whereas the latter just breaks up the integrand for various values of omega and q. Both give me the same issue.
Also, I'm wondering what the difference is between a response function and a dielectric function. Both phrases are thrown around a lot and I can't make heads or tails of how they are related.

Comment: If what you refer to is the one given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindhard_theory, the integration over $\omega$ seems to be a classic case for an application of the Cauchy formula. Should probably do that first.